# Revalidate field with custom directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, validation, directive

I have this scenario where a field is invalid due to another selection on the form. When that selection changes I want to revalidate. I tried calling $setViewValue on the field when the selection changes, but that doesn't refire the validation. Any ideas?

I have a hack working, but I would prefer a clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

Write a directive, say **validation**, and place it on your field in the definition of this directive in the:

```
link:function(scope,element,args){
    element.bind('onfocus',function(){

        // Your logic
    })

    // Similarly, bind other relevant events like key presses, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and found a workaround/feature that appears to be undocumented. If you need to trigger ngModelController to revalidate, you can either do:

```
ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(value, 'your event name', true);
```

or if you don't need to update your model value

```
ngModelCtrl.$commitViewValue(true);
```

The true in both cases above is a flag for revalidation. Without this flag, the issue I was running into was that if the model value does not change, then angular simply skips the validation. I am using this way to manually mark a custom control as **$dirty**

Source:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1843

Answer (score 0):

Put a ng-change on your select and broadcast an event in it:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("selectChangedEvent");
```

Then, in a directive you have placed on your field, simply put in the link function:

```
$rootScope.$on("selectChangedEvent", () => ngModelCtrl.$validate());
```

[$validate runs each of the registered validators of your field.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$validate)